# How do I pass a prop to complete the URL for my endpoint in React class Component?

Tags: reactjs, class, material-ui

I am using the URL below to (endpoint) in order to fetch the data i need to create a chart.
How do I complete the URL from "outside" the class with the symbol needed for the URL to work?

Code:

```
export default class HighLowChart extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {data: []}
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        // const endpoint = 'https://www.randyconnolly.com/funwebdev/3rd/api/stocks/history.php?symbol=amzn';
        const endpoint = `https://www.randyconnolly.com/funwebdev/3rd/api/stocks/history.php?symbol=${this.props}`;


        fetch(endpoint)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {this.setState({data:data})
        })
      }
```

the commented endpoint works but when I use the HighLowChart component on my page I would like to be able to complete the URL from providing it a prop if that is possible. like below:

```
<Box sx={{marginBottom: "2rem" }}>
   <HighLowChart props={symbol}/>
</Box>
//where symbol in this case would be 'amzn'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Always share props to the parent child in above mentioned way. So in HightLowChart component your component will receive props like this

- this.props.symbol

Comment: During sending props your HightLowChart component should look like this <HighLowChart symbol={symbol} />